# Show homebrew upgrade information again

Tags: macos, upgrade, logging, homebrew

When upgrading a package with homebrew, there are several information shown e.g. breaking changes or things to do after installation. 
Is it possible to show this information after the upgrade again? I don't always have time to read though all of the details. I want to revisit this info when something is not working properly with a package.

Is this possible with homebrew itself, or do I need to record console output of the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called "caveats" and are shown again once you type:

```
brew info <package>
```

There's also a third party program that just lists caveats: [`homebrew-caveats`](https://github.com/rafaelgarrido/homebrew-caveats).